# Armadillo/C++: How to assign elements from a vector to a cube tube?

Tags: c++, cube, armadillo

Suppose I have a 3x3x4 cube `Q` (i.e. a cube having 3 rows, three columns, and 4 slices) and a column vector `C` with 4 elements (i.e. as many elements as the slices of Q). Is there a way for me to use C to populate a tube of Q?

I tried the following:

```
# include <armadillo>

cube Q(3,3,4);
mat C(4,1, fill::zeros);
Q.tube(0, 0) = C;
```

but it didn't work (got a runtime exception). Is there a way to achieve the goal without looping explicitly through the tube and the vector elements?

**SOLVED**
The code above works just fine. It turns out I was probably doing *something else* (don't know what) wrong the first time I tried it. Thanks to darcamo for pointing out the code actually works!

Comment: what is the type of `Q`?

Comment: It's a cube, as stated above. The default element type is double, I believe.

Comment: `cube` is not a standard c++ type. Please tell us where does it come from.

Comment: My question, as you can read in the title of the post as well as in the keywords I used, is about the Armadillo library for c++. Cube is a class defined in Armadillo ,and it's basically a three-dimensional matrix. In my question, I assume familiarity with the Armadillo library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange. I try it and it worked just fine for me. Try converting the `C` matrix into an `arma::vec` before with the assignment.

```cpp
Q.tube(0, 0) = arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from(C);
```

Since a "tube" is one-dimensional it does not make sense to assign a full 2D matrix to it anyway. Although in your case it's a column matrix and it should work.

I didn't need to convert it, but it is worth trying, since some features in armadillo might not be available due to different flags, compiler support, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right: my code works as it is! I don't know what I was doing when I first tried it and got the runtime error, but now it works just fine. I didn't change anything in terms of flags or preprocessor statements, so I suspect I was doing something wrong without realizing it.